# Найти среднее арифметическое чисел, меньших т, и среднее геометрическое чисел, больших либо равных т

Tags: c#

Даны n положительных и отрицательных чисел и действительное число m. Найти среднее арифметическое чисел, меньших т, и среднее геометрическое чисел, больших либо равных т

Не совсем понимаю суть задачи но попытаюсь расписать как понял.

1. создаём два цикла которые будут генерировать N положительных чисел и N отрицательных

**действительное число m ?? Вот это не понятно**

2. берём одно число положительное складываем с одним отрицательным и делим на 2, сравниваем потом с ЧЕМ ??
3. Среднее геометрическое чисел это умножаем все числа которые вывел счетчик цикла сравниваем с чем ?

Comment: m и т как связаны? или вы латинскую m как русскую т читаете? А задача достаточно ясно описана. Числа даны, генерировать не надо.

Comment: Может `m` всё-таки не «действительное» (какое бы оно ещё могло быть), а «положительное»? Потому что среднее геометрическое имеет смысл только для положительных чисел.

Comment: Почему вы решили, что нужно складывать положительные числа с отрицательными? Вам нужно отобрать числа больше т и отдельно меньше т, в них могут попасть произвольные числа, попарно ничего брать не надо. Почитайте определения среднего арифметического и среднего геометрического, там всё очень просто. И ещё раз: сравниваем с m (или т?) для отбора сначала, а потом уже из отобранных чисел считаем среднее арифметическое/геометрическое.